# Do I need to unsubscribe from Observable.of?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

So, basically, new to rxjs and wanted to know,

Do I need to unsubscribe from Observable.of(data) or in newer rxjs versions, just plain of(data)?

i.e.

```
import {of} from 'rxjs';
const sub = of(data).subscribe();
```

is this necessary?

```
sub.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Do I need to? No. Should I? Yes.

Comment: In your code, sub is an observable, not a subscription so calling unsubscribe will error. const sub = of(data).subscribe(_ => { // do something }); will give you a subscription.

Answer (score 5):

There are finite and infinite Observables as best described in this [article](https://www.seangwright.me/blog/development/unsubscribe-angular-2-http-observables/).

#### Finite Observables

are completed in a specific foreseeable time frame, e.g. a network request or your `Observable.of()` call.

#### Infinite Observables

might never be completed, e.g. Observing click events.

#### Answer

While there is no real need to unsubscribe from **finite** Observables it's considered best practice to unsubscribe from every observable as you normally don't really know if it is really finite.

In order to not pile up multiple subscriptions in your code it is best to use advanced rxjs features, as shown in this [article](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87).

#### Why should I unsubscribe from an [Observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html)?

An Observable is a stream of events. You can subscribe to this stream and get updates as the stream generates events with the `subscribe` function

```
.subscribe(
  onNext => {
    // Called if there was a normal event, e.g. data is emitted
  },
  onError => {
    // Called if there was an Error
  },
  onComplete => {
    // Called if the event stream ends OR an Error is encountered
  }
)
```

Every Subscription takes up space in memory and as long as the Observable does not complete the subscriptions won't terminate (but will still receive updates with the `onNext()`-Function, even if for example in angular the component gets destroyed). 
In order to prevent unexpected behavior and memory leaks you have to unsubscribe. [Click to read more](https://netbasal.com/why-its-important-to-unsubscribe-from-rxjs-subscription-a7a6455d6a02)

Answer (score 4):

More specific answer regarding RxJS is that you don't unsubscribe from `of` because it's an Observable that emits a `complete` notification when it's done emitting `next` values you gave it.

For example with this Observable `of(1)` the order of notifications is the following:

1. `next` notification with the value `1`.
2. `complete` notification that tells subscribers that this source Observable is done emitting anything.

`Subscriber` objects after receiving `complete` notification unsubscribe automatically:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L147
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L123